# Sliders cannot be dragged in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Here is a basic page that describes my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="stufflist">
                <div><input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="4"/></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        </div><!-- /page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

If you plonk this somewhere in a file and open it in a web browser, you will see that jquery mobile has initialized a slider, as it should.  But it can't be dragged.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot explain why, but when I  changed the included jQuery script to 1.6.4 (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js) it worked fine.

Comment: That worked fine - if you'd added that as an answer, I'd have given you an up-vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 does not officially support use with jQuery 1.7.1 as sometimes suggested in other posts.  Check out the [jqm download area](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/26/jquery-mobile-1-0-1-released/#download) and observe the recommended usage.

To get a better answer from the jquery mobile team, [check out this forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/does-jquery-mobile-support-jquery-1-7). It should be supported in jqm 1.1.

Hope this helps!